# Append image in function jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, image

Good evening.
I have this jquery code which allows me, once you press the Enter key, to post a comment.

Fattio that I run an append with the username and the content that the user wants to publish.

In addition to the username I would also like to "hang" the profile picture using their path. How do I post a photo?

Thanks for your help. Here's the code:

```
function commento_post(id_post)
{
    $('.form-commento'+id_post).click(function ()
    {
        $('#ins_commento'+id_post).keydown(function (e)
        {
            var message = $("#commento"+id_post).val();
            var username = $("#username").val();
            var id_user = $("#id_user").val();
            if(e.keyCode === 13)
            {
                $.ajax(
                {
                    type: 'POST',
                    url: 'http://localhost/laravel/public/index.php/post/ins_commento',
                    data: { commento: message, id_post: id_post },
                    success: function(data) 
                    {
                        $('#commento'+id_post).val('');
                        $('#commentscontainer'+id_post).append
                        (
                            /*$(".username-commento"+id_post).html
                            (*/
                                $('<a/>', 
                                { 
                                    text : username, href : 'http://localhost/laravel/public/index.php/utente/'+id_user
                                }).css({'font-weight':'bold'})
                            //)
                        ).append(' ').append(message).append($('<br/>'));

                        var el = $('#numero_commenti'+id_post);
                        var num = parseInt(el.text());
                        el.text(num + 1);
                    }
                });
            }
        });
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your success function, you could simplify everything quite a bit in the following way while not using jQuery `append` so much, but just using a variable to store your code and then appending it in one go. This will allow you to append all sort of elements, it's easily parseable for the you and it reduces the amount of calls you have to make.

```
// Add whatever you want your final HTML to look like to this variable
var html = "<a href='http://localhost/laravel/public/index.php/utente/" + id_user + "' style='font-weight: bold;'>" + username + "</a>";
    html += message;
    // add an image
    html += "<img src='path/to/image.jpg' />"
    html += "<br />";
// append to code you constructed above in one go
$('#commentscontainer' + id_post).append(html);
```

### Update

I amended an incorrect quote and changed `+ id_user + "`to `+ id_user + "'`, which makes everything after it work.

Comment: Thank you very much! Function.
One last question. Is there a way to set the width and height of the image in the code that I've posted?

Thanks!

Comment: @Francesco Its just adding html, so `html += '<img src="" width="x" and height="x" />'` will work precisely like it would if you'd have written it directly to the DOM.

Comment: Written in this way gives me error

var html = '<img src="images/provvisorie/immagine-profilo.png" width="20" and height="20" />";

Comment: @Francesco be very wary when using the quotes - if your string is surrounded by double quotes, use single quotes inside and via versa. Or escape any quotes your are using by prefixing them with  backslash. This is yours amended: `var html = '<img src="images/provvisorie/immagine-profilo.png" width="20" height="20" />';` - Also, apart from that I accidentally typed 'and' in my previous comments code. That should obviously not be there :s sorry! If this works, could you mark it as correct?

Comment: It works and I thank you! But unfortunately I can not even mark it as correct. I tried several times but the system prevents me

Comment: @Francesco You should always be able to mark something as the answer on your own question. Just click the checkmark below the count next to my question. The bold is a style, again added in the same way as regular HTML so `style="font-weight: bold;"` should embolden the text. CORRECTION: the bold does not work because I forgot to add a closing `'` just after your url. Check amended code.

Comment: I'm sorry, I mistranslated me! Sign now correctly! Thank you and sorry again